# SQL Query : Union with order by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having a small problem with SQL Server 2012 with a UNION query.

I have a following simple select statement But it does not return data in order as per the sl_no column

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(SELECT '1'SL_NO, '10000' [KEY METRIC] UNION
SELECT '2', '5000' UNION
SELECT '3', '1000' UNION
SELECT '4', '750' UNION
SELECT '5', '500' UNION
SELECT '6', '250' UNION
SELECT '7', '100' UNION
SELECT '8', '50' UNION
SELECT '9', '25' UNION
SELECT '10', '10' UNION
SELECT '11', '5' UNION
SELECT '12', 'AAL' UNION
SELECT '13', 'Standard Deviation' UNION
SELECT '14', 'Coefficient of Variation') A 
order by SL_NO
```

I need this data in following form

```
|1  |10000    |
|2  |5000     |
|3  |1000     | 
|4  |750      |
|5  |500      |
|6  |250      |
|7  |100      |
|8  |50       | 
|9  |25       | 
|10 |10       |
|11 |5        | 
|12 |AAL      |
|13 |Standard Deviation|
|14 |Coefficient of Variation|
```

Comment: Ordering a `string` is different to a `numeric`.

Comment: You could simply use `1,2,3` as integer instead of `'1','2','3'` varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(SELECT 1 SL_NO, '10000' [KEY METRIC] UNION
SELECT 2, '5000' UNION
SELECT 3, '1000' UNION
SELECT 4, '750' UNION
SELECT 5, '500' UNION
SELECT 6, '250' UNION
SELECT 7, '100' UNION
SELECT 8, '50' UNION
SELECT 9, '25' UNION
SELECT 10, '10' UNION
SELECT 11, '5' UNION
SELECT 12, 'AAL' UNION
SELECT 13, 'Standard Deviation' UNION
SELECT 14, 'Coefficient of Variation') A 
order by SL_NO Asc
```

Answer (score 2):

why store int as varchar

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(SELECT 1 SL_NO, '10000' [KEY METRIC] UNION
SELECT 2, '5000' UNION
SELECT 3, '1000' UNION
SELECT 4, '750' UNION
SELECT 5, '500' UNION
SELECT 6, '250' UNION
SELECT 7, '100' UNION
SELECT 8, '50' UNION
SELECT 9, '25' UNION
SELECT 10, '10' UNION
SELECT 11, '5' UNION
SELECT 12, 'AAL' UNION
SELECT 13, 'Standard Deviation' UNION
SELECT 14, 'Coefficient of Variation') A 
order by SL_NO
```

Comment: I add sl_no to get data in order.. any new idea to get data in specified form?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
ORDER BY CAST(SL_NO AS INT)
```